# nextInt stored inside an array Java

Tags: java

So I have this this code:

```
int[] player1 = new int[5]; // first player
            try{

               for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

                   player1[i] = keyin.nextInt();}
               }
           catch(NumberFormatException e){

               System.out.println("Player 2 : ")

           }
int[] player2 = new int[5]; // Second Player

                try{

               for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

                   player2[i] = keyin.nextInt();}
               }
           catch(NumberFormatException e){

               System.out.println("Player 3 : ");  
           }
```

I'm trying to get the user to input 5 or less integers for betting purposes, but somehow my code keeps forcing the user to input 5 orelse it won't catch and go to the second player.. How do I change this?

Comment: `nextInt` should be followed by `nextLine` to remove the carriage return which still remains within the `System.in` buffer...otherwise `nextInt` will fail the next time it is called

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I write that exactly? (Newbie coder!)

Comment: `keyin.nextLine();` ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You said followed by nextLine?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a for loop to request that the user inputs 5 numbers

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

                   player1[i] = keyin.nextInt();}
               }
```

This is saying that the user must input a number until i increments itself to 5, meaning 5 inputs.

What you could do is make a while loop saying:

```
while(keyin.hasNextInt()){

}
```

And then use an if statement that breaks out of the loop once the input reaches 5 characters, or if the user breaks out of the loop by pressing a key on the keyboard.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the user only has to press anything else but an int        it has to look like `Player1: 1 2 3 4` and on the following line `Player2: 3 2 1`

Comment: I would put the while loop outside the for loop?